# How do I add Android user (linux level) to a group?

Tags: linux, accounts

groupadd and useradd aren't available, so how I can add a user (app's assigned user) to a group?

Also, the file /etc/group does not exist and I couldn't find where Android saves this information. (googling/greping).

Comment: Take a look into the file `/data/system/packages.list` (root required).

Comment: This does not tell us what you are trying to achieve through that. Please give us the whole picture.

Comment: i want to make genymotion shared directory accessible to a non-root user/app. on a plain linux you just add the user to a specific group. i want to do the same in android

Comment: @Bnaya where is the "genymotion shared directory" located and what users/apps you want to allow access for this directory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an android phone in front of me, but I imagine you could just edit `/etc/group` and add the user to a group. Find the group you want to add them to and insert a comma, then the user name.

Example :

```
sambashare:x:115:sam,sally,yourNewUser
```

Where the first column is the group name, then the second column is group passwd (leave it an x), groupID and then the users.

Comment: cat /etc/group                                                                                                                                                                                  
cat: /etc/group: No such file or directory

Comment: I was trying that before, should have mention that in the question